# Problems with anticaptcha plugin in selenium python

Tags: python, selenium, plugins, automation

I've recently started using selenium for a project I've been working on for a while that involves automation. One of the roadblocks in the plan was the ReCaptcha system, so I decided to use anti-captcha as the service that would solve the captchas when my bot encountered it. I properly installed the plugin and found some test code with selenium on their [site](https://antcpt.com/eng/information/recaptcha-2-selenium.html).

I've followed the instructions and am receiving no errors while the code is running, but after it times out I am receiving the error message pertaining to this line at the very end:

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 120).until(lambda x: x.find_element_by_css_selector('.antigate_solver.solved'))
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong and would appreciate some help figuring out the problem so I can get the service running. Apologies for my formatting and if my question is not very good I'm new to this.

Comment: Sounds like they aren't solving the captcha within 120 seconds.  What is the exception/error message?

Comment: also not sure why they are doing it this way... seems like you should get the token straight from their server... are you sure this isn't a scam?

Comment: @pcalkins they're getting the token from the frontend. That way they don't have to maintain different code for each language they want to support. Use the browser console to see what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message received that indicates there is a problem with the last line?

Does your code include the send form instruction after this line:

## Sending form browser.find_element_by_css_selector('input[type=submit]').click()

You may search for more information here:
https://python-anticaptcha.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#solve-recaptcha

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't actually added exact errror you are getting, i believe it is a `TimeoutException error`. Go to your browser console and check for the error shown there. it will most likely be something to related to the api key and low funds in your account.